# Why is ZFC's sanity not axiomatized?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

By ***Standard Finite Set Theory***, I mean the theory coined in a langauge that extends first order logic with the below mentioned omega-inference rule, that has the following extra-logical axioms, on top of the first order identity axioms:

**Extensionality:** $\forall XY [\forall Z(Z \in X \leftrightarrow Z \in Y) \to X=Y]$

**Empty:** $\exists X \forall Y (Y \not \in X)$

**Finite construction:** for $n=1,2,3,...$

$\forall X_1,..,X_n \exists X \forall Y (Y \in X \leftrightarrow Y=X_1 \lor ..\lor Y=X_n)$

Define: $ \mathcal P(A)=X \equiv_{df} \forall Y (Y \in X \leftrightarrow Y \subseteq A) $

Define: for $i=0,1,2,... \\ \mathcal P_0(\emptyset)=\emptyset \\ \mathcal P_{i+1}(\emptyset)=\mathcal P(\mathcal P_i(\emptyset))$

***Omega-inference-rule for finite sets***: if $\psi(X)$ is a formula in which only symbol $X$ occur free, and in which symbol $X$ never occurs bound; then:

FROM SCHEMA: $for \ i=1,2,3,... \\ \forall X (X \in P_i(\emptyset) \to \psi(X))$

INFER: $\forall X (\psi(X))$

Now I think this theory is complete. The model of this theory would be the set $\sf HF$ of all well founded hereditarily standard finite sets.

Now a theory $T$ is to be labeled as $\sf HF$-Sane, if and only if every sentence $s^T$ of $T$ having all of its quantifiers completely bounded by the set $V^T_\omega$ of all well founded hereditarily finite sets of $T$, that is convertible to a sentence $s*^T$ in the language of this theory by mere removal of all bounding symbols $V^T_\omega$ from $s^T$; would have the sentence $s*^T$ being a theorem of this theory. In nutshell $T$ is $\sf HF$-Sane if and only if it doesn't prove of its well founded hereditarily finite sets some statement that is not true of sets in $\sf HF$!

Now it is very demanding that a set theory, especially one that is thought of serving as a foundation of mathematics, be assumed to be $\sf HF$-Sane. And I think that $\sf HF$-Sanity of a theory is the same as *arithmetical*-Soundness of it. But since we are speaking about sets, then its more prudent to speak in terms of $\sf HF$-Sanity of a set theory.

> Now why we don't see "$\sf ZFC \text { is HF}$-$\sf \text{Sane}$" as an axiom extending ZFC?

Comment: What does the term $\omega$ refer to? If you regard $\omega$ as being defined by the theory (e.g., the smallest infinite ordinal), then the problem is that the theory will have different models with different $\omega$s, and so the $\omega$ rule becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @provocateur, $\omega$ here is just a name for a rule, it doesn't exist as an object in this theory at all. All objects of this theory are well founded hereditarily standard finite sets. Ok, I'll change it, just to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - are you just asking why we don't work in ZFC + "ZFC is HF-sane" instead of ZFC? If so, an immediate response is that that just begs further iteration (why not ZFC + "ZFC is HF-sane" + "ZFC + "ZFC is HF-sane" is HF-sane"?), so it's not very satisfying. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Also, you write: "In nutshell  is -Sane if and only if it doesn't prove of its well founded hereditarily finite sets some statement that is not true of sets in ! [...] I think that -Sanity of a theory is the same as arithmetical-Sanity of it." This is true (well, the term is "arithmetical *soundness*") so why not just say *that*? It would make the question much shorter and easier to read; there's no payoff I can see of introducing a new notion.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, no the other iterations are not important.

Comment: @Zuhair **Why not**? Some sort of argument has to be advanced here ...

Comment: Finally, SFST is **not** categorical - in particular, any structure elementarily equivalent to HF will satisfy it. (This doesn't affect things, though, as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I thought SFST is equivalent to True arithmetic. And I thought the latter is complete.

Comment: @Zuhair "Complete" and "categorical" are different things. It is indeed complete, but it's not categorical.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it's both complete and Categorical, that's what I thought.

Comment: @Zuhair But it's **not** categorical, that's what I'm telling you. Anything elementarily equivalent to HF is a model of it. Again, it's complete but not categorical.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, OK, I'll need to remove that part then. Thanks

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I think we need to have at least one assertion about ZFC's HF-sanity (HF-soundness), the rest of iterations won't change that.

Comment: @Zuhair Again, **why**? Why is $T$ = ZFC + "ZFC is arithmetically sound" better than ZFC but $T$ + "$T$ is arithmetically sound" is no better than $T$? There needs to be some sort of argument here for why we need one layer but stopping after one layer is fine. This is especially true since ZFC **already** has a sanity principle built in: namely, for every finite subtheory $S$ of ZFC, ZFC proves that $S$ is arithmetically sound (by the Reflection Principle).

Comment: For your finite construction axiom, you use—and therefore already need to have—the natural numbers. While in the usual modern formulation, sets are defined first, and then the natural numbers are built from sets. Which implies the natural numbers are not yet available when constructing set theory itself.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn't say that $T$+"$T$ is arithemtically sound" is not better than $T$. I'm only saying that our prime interest is in the arithmetical soundness (thus HF-sanity) of ZFC, further iteration up the scale might be beneficial, but lets at first do the first step, then go further. At least one step of soundness needs to be added, that's to give some sort of justification for the "set" theory we want it to found mathematics. Iterating further would be related to justification of something that is not merely set theory.

Comment: @Zuhair "At least one step of soundness needs to be added, that's to give some sort of justification for the "set" theory we want it to found mathematics." I disagree with both points here. First, I don't understand the need here - especially given that ZFC already proves the arithmetical soundness of each of its finite fragments. Second, if we do buy that we need to add further soundness, I don't see why it's okay to stop there since adding soundness principles add arithmetic consequences which in turn need to be justified. So I just don't buy the argument you're making here at all.

Comment: @celtschk, thanks for that point. But its no big deal, I can simply replace this axiom with an axiom of singletons and Boolean union. It would do the job.

Comment: @Zuhair: In your Omega-inference you are using the natural numbers again.

Comment: @NoahSchweber proving every finite sub-theory of it being arithmetically sound is good, but not enough. Of course we need the whole theory to be arithmetically sound. Why should we trust it then? If we can't trust its decisions on the hereditarily finite set world, then how can we trust its decisions on the infinite realm?

Comment: @Zuhair But again that same objection can be leveled at the stronger theory. In fact, that objection says that no theory is fully satisfying - *which I think is true!* Besides, remember that any theorem of ZFC (about HF or anything else) is in fact a theorem of a finite fragment of ZFC, so that trust is already built in to a certain extent. I really just don't see the point of this.

Comment: @celtschk, yes of course, those are the standard naturals, that help build the herediarily standard finite sets, which is something more complicated than just having a flat set of standard naturals.

Comment: But then, you already have to assume that standard arithmetic is sound in order to even justify formulating that axiom. Therefore every assertion of the soundness of standard arithmetic based on that axiom will be circular.

Comment: @NoahSchweber if ZFC is HF-sane, but it cannot prove that about itself (due to Godel's theorem..), then adding this assertion to it would be a true theory that we ought to work with. If one doesn't add this at least one step, one would be tempted to investigate unsound versions of ZFC, which is not a good venue for a foundational theory of mathematics to open.

Comment: @Zuhair: An inconsistent theory doesn't suddenly become consistent just by adding an axiom that says “this theory is consistent”.

Comment: @Zuhair And yet again (and for the last time - I see no gain in reiterating this), I find that argument incredibly weak: I don't buy that the problem is serious and even granting its seriousness I don't buy that that significantly improves the situation. I think we've hit the point of diminishing returns, so I'll bow out here, but I think this is part of the answer to your question: your claims of significant objection and significant improvement are not universally shared.

Comment: @celtschk, I think you are confused. Because being "sound" means capturing standard arithmetic.

Comment: But then, the very fact that we can define standard arithmetic in ZFC should already prove that ZFC captures it. Otherwise, its not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes I agree that it is not universally shared. But I just need to mention something. If I had said that $T$ is not acceptable as a foundational theory unless its $HF$-Sanity is added to it, then your argument about upward iterative begging of sanity is valid against this stance! But that was not my stance! What I'm stating is that a theory $T$ is not acceptable as a foundational theory unless there is a sub-theory $T'$ of $T$ such that $T=T' + T' \text { is HF-Sane}$, accordingly $ZFC$ is not acceptable as a foundational theory, but $ZFC + ZFC \text{ is HF-Sane}$ is acceptable!

Comment: continuation... You may say, but along the same token, then the next tier theory that is let T=ZFC + ZFC is HF-Sane, and let T+ T is HF-Sane be a foundational theory. And my response to this is YES, it is of course a foundational theory, I'm not stopping at all. You have a whole lot of foundational theories above ZFC + ZFC is HF-Sane. It only happens that along that particular tower ZFC+ZFC is HF-Sane is the smallest of all those foundational theories.

Comment: @Zuhair "a theory  is not acceptable as a foundational theory unless there is a sub-theory ′ of  such that =′+′ is HF-Sane" And I see no justification for this - actually, I'd claim the opposite (that stopping at a "successor level" is unnatural).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, No one is stopping at a successor level. See my second comment. Just above this one of  yours.

Comment: @celtschk. You cannot capture all of standard arithmetic in ZFC. That's the point. ZFC only manages to capture a very small fragment of standard arithmetic. That's why we are speaking of "Sanity" of it. Standard arithmetic is not effectively generated using first order logical theories. When we are speaking of Sanity here we are referring to it as a property of effective first order theories. (Apology: in my prior comment I meant by being sound (or sane) as capturing SOME of standard arithmetic, and not capturing any non-standard arithmetic)

Comment: But AFAICT your SFST is first order, too, and therefore cannot avoid non-standard models either.

Comment: @celtschk, Not its NOT! Its definitely not an effectively generated first order theory! It cannot  have non-standard models!

Comment: It's not effectively generated, but @celtschk said only that it's first order. That looks correct, and it implies the existence of nonstandard models.

Comment: As I said above, any $M\equiv HF$ satisfies your theory. The nontrivial part of this claim is showing that if $M\equiv HF$ then $M$ satisfies the appropriate $\omega$-rule. Suppose for each $i$ we have $M\models\forall X(X\in P_i(\emptyset)\rightarrow\psi(X))$. By elementarity we also have for each $i$ that $HF\models\forall X(X\in P_i(\emptyset)\rightarrow\psi(X))$. So $HF\models\forall X(\psi(X))$. But then by elementarity *again* we have $M\models\forall X(\psi(X))$. The point is that independent of the complexity of the new rule the *result* is a first-order (hence non-categorical) theory.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Noah Schweber: if I  change the infinitely long condition of the omega rule to: $for \ i=1,2,3,...; for \   n=0,1,2,3,... \\\forall X_1,..,X_n \forall X (X \in P_i (\emptyset) \land X=\{X_1,..,X_n\}  \to \psi(X))$ would that make matters differ. If not then why the situation is different with this posting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218773/is-pa%cf%89-rule-and-zermelo-infinityevery-set-is-finite-%cf%89-set-rule-equi-inte

Comment: @Zuhair PA + $\omega$-rule isn't categorical either. It's complete but not categorical. (The argument from my above comment demonstrates the failure of categoricity here as well: these rules are really **closure operators** on the set of first-order sentences - a structure satisfies the rule iff its theory is its own closure with respect to that operator. So whether a structure satisfies such a rule is determined entirely by the structure's theory, hence for any rule $R$ of this type the set of structures satisfying $R$ is an [elementary class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_class).)

Comment: So there is no tension to be explained away. (Since this is all getting away from the main point of the OP, I suggest that if you are still interested you ask a separate question about this - I'd be happy to expand my comments here into an answer.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber. DONE!

Comment: @celtschk, it is not in itself exactly first order, but it turns to be equivalent to some first order theory, after I saw the comments I now realize that it is not categorical and it cannot avoid non-standards, as you said, but its the most true first order theory about hereditarily finite sets, so I think its prudent to speak about ZFC being HF-sane as I defined (in the relative sense of first order). I still think that if T is to be labeled as a foundational theory, then there must be a fragment S of T such that T=S + S is HF-Sane. If there is no such S, then T is not foundational. ...cont.

Comment: ...cont. so accodingly ZFC is not foundational, but ZFC+ZFC is HF-Sane is foundational. Of course higher tiers of that are all foundational as well, so there is no stop at any successor level, so if S=ZFC+ZFC is HF-Sane, then S+S is HF-Sane is ALSO foundational, and all upwards iteratied tieres of that are also foundational.