# Is Categoricity preserved under equi-interpretability?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

Is PA + Omega rule categorical?

Is the theory ZF-Inf.+Fin+ Omega rule  categorical?

According to the posting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218773/is-pa%CF%89-rule-and-zermelo-infinityevery-set-is-finite-%CF%89-set-rule-equi-inte), ZF-Inf.+Fin+Omega rule is proved equiv-interpretable with PA + omega rule, both of which are complete theories. So would that equi-interpretability also prove the former theory to be categorical?

The main concern is if theory ZF-Inf.+Fin+Omega rule can allow for non-standard models of it, i.e. if it allows for existence of sets that are not well founded hereditarily standard finite sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'll address the background question: **neither theory is categorical.** I'll treat first the specific case of PA + $\omega$-rule, then state a more general result (which shows that we never get categoricity in this way - and so in particular the answer to the "main concern" is *yes*). Finally I'll give a strong *negative* answer to the title question.

---

Here's a proof that PA + $\omega$-rule is not categorical:

> Claim: if $M$ satisfies true arithmetic (= $Th(\mathbb{N})$), then $M$ satisfies PA + $\omega$-rule.

This immediately implies that PA + $\omega$-rule has nonstandard models, since no first-order theory with at least one infinite model is categorical (by compactness, in the form of the [upwards Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Upward_part)).

*Proof*: The only nontrivial piece is to show that $M$ satisfies the $\omega$-rule. We prove this by elementarity. *(I'll conflate standard natural numbers and their corresponding numerals for simplicity.)*

- Suppose $M\models\varphi(n)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
- By elementarity, we have $\mathbb{N}\models\varphi(n)$ for each $n$.
- So $\mathbb{N}\models\forall x\varphi(x)$.
- By elementarity again, we have $M\models\forall x\varphi(x)$.

And we're done. $\quad\Box$

*(In fact, using this we can prove that PA + $\omega$-rule "is" just true arithmetic, albeit a particularly nice presentation of it. And the theory ZF - Inf + "HF-rule" similarly "is" just $Th(HF)$, the proof being basically identical.)*

> Note that this **does not mean** that the $\omega$-rule is valueless! "PA + $\omega$-rule" is an interesting different description of true arithmetic and suggests a number of related non-a-priori-first-order variations which turn out to be quite interesting and important.
>
> It also suggests studying the logical aspects of problems of the form "Find the least fixed point of such-and-such closure operator." This leads to a bit of higher recursion theory - namely [metarecursion theory, or in more modern language $\alpha$-recursion theory in the special case of $\alpha=\omega_1^{CK}$](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1951/8ac9edc0e6aa368e074e002d968e487b5ccf.pdf) - since the least fixed points of "computable" closure operators on the naturals are exactly the $\Pi^1_1$ (or meta-r.e., or $\omega_1^{CK}$-r.e.) sets of natural numbers. *(For the left-to-right direction of this claim, note that the least fixed point of $\mathcal{R}$ is the set of $x$ satisfying "For all $\mathcal{R}$-closed $A$ we have $x\in A$;" the other direction is a bit more complicated and uses ranking functions.)*
>
> (It also leads to the study of inductive definitions in proof theory, but I know basically nothing about that. It is important, though!)

---

Note that we used very little in the above - all that mattered was that each instance of the $\omega$-rule was "triggered" by a collection of first-order sentences, so we could argue via elementarity that "triggered in $M$ $\implies$ triggered in $\mathbb{N}$ $\implies$ goal is true in $\mathbb{N}$ $\implies$ goal is true in $M$."

This argument lets us prove the following general result. Say that an *infinitary rule* $\mathcal{R}$ is a set of pairs of the form $\langle \Gamma,\varphi\rangle$ for $\Gamma$ a set of sentences and $\varphi$ a sentence *(intended meaning: "from $\Gamma$ infer $\varphi$")*. For a structure $M$ and an infinitary rule $\mathcal{R}$, say that $M$ satisfies $\mathcal{R}$ iff for all $\langle\Gamma,\varphi\rangle\in\mathcal{R}$, if $M\models\Gamma$ then $M\models\varphi$. Then:

> $(*)\quad$ The set of structures satisfying an infinitary rule $\mathcal{R}$ is always an elementary class - so we never get categoricity via infinitary rules.

Note that this really does imply the particular cases of interest in the OP: we can always add a first-order theory $T$ to a rule $\mathcal{R}$ by considering the new infinitary rule $$\mathcal{R}[T]=\mathcal{R}\cup\{\langle\emptyset,\varphi\rangle:\varphi\in T\}.$$ So just apply $(*)$ above to "$\omega$-rule$[{PA}]$."

---

As to the answer in the above question, it depends precisely what you mean by "equi-interpretability" (note that here we're talking a priori about *non-first-order* theories, in order for this to be nontrivial).

The simplest interpretation of this term is fairly loose: say that $T$ and $S$ are *simply equi-interpretable* iff every model of one interprets some model of the other. This **does not preserve** categoricity: consider $T=$ second-order PA versus $S=$ "second-order PA + a structureless set" (that is, a model of $S$ consists of a model of second-order PA plus an infinite structureless set). $T$ and $S$ are trivially simply equi-interpretable, but $S$ is clearly not categorical (just change the cardinality of the structureless set part).

- In fact, note that this shows that simple equi-interpretability doesn't even preserve *completeness* - the structureless set part of a model of $S$ could have one element, or two elements, or ...

One level up is *bi-interpretability* - roughly speaking, this means that given any model $M$ of $T$ we can find a model $N$ of $S$ interpreted in $T$ and a model $M'$ of $T$ interpreted in $S$ "definably in $M$" (and vice versa). But the idea above shows that this *also* does not preserve categoricity or even completeness - consider now a (non-first-order) theory $T$ pinning down some uncountable structure $M$ up to isomorphism, and the new theory $S$ = "$T$ + a structureless set."

Instead you need something even stronger - that there is a "definable" (in some sense) bijection between the classes of isomorphism types. But that trivially preserves categoricity, since the existence of *any* bijection between the classes of isomorphism types tells us that the theories have the same number of models.

Comment: But, the essential matter (to me) is if ZF-Inf.+Fin+Omega rule can speak of non-standard finite sets? I was under the naive impression that as PA+omega rule *is* true arithmetic, then ZF-Inf.+Fin.+Omega rule *is* true finite set theory. i.e. it only speaks of standard finite sets, thereby only of hereditarily standard finite sets. So my concern is that if the loss of categoricity with both theories implies the possibility of those theories speaking about non-standard naturals or non-standard finite sets?

Comment: @Zuhair Per my above answer, neither is categorical. Both are complete however, and indeed as you guess the structures satisfying ZF - Inf. + "HF-rule" are exactly the models of $Th(HF)$ (basically, duplicate the same argument for PA + $\omega$-rule and $Th(\mathbb{N})$). So in each case we have nonstandard models, but all those nonstandard models have the same theory as the standard model.

Comment: Meanwhile, I don't know what it means to "speak of" something - certainly nonstandardness isn't definable in either context in any sense, since if it were the sentence "there are no nonstandard objects" would be part of the theory. I'd say the actual takeaway is: *infinitary rules still yield first-order theories*, and as such any time we have a first-order theory + some infinitary rules we always wind up with something equivalent - in the semantic sense - to a first-order theory. (Of course, the description by infinitary rules may be much simpler than the description as a first-order theory.)

Comment: well the infinity rules can result sometimes in complete theories, and so we won't wind up with an equivalent *effective* first order theory, however we may end up with a non-effective equivalent FIRST order theory. It seems that ALL first order theories, allow non-standards, whether they are effective or not.

Comment: @Zuhair "well the infinity rules [...] won't wind up with an equivalent effective first order theory, [but] a non-effective equivalent FIRST order theory." Yes, that's exactly right - and the point of the last two sentences of my previous comment. "It seems that ALL first order theories, allow non-standards, whether they are effective or not." True (well, as long as the theory in question has at least one infinite model) - this is an immediate consequence of compactness (in the form of [upwards Lowenheim-Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Upward_part)).

Comment: Putting that second point another way: a first-order theory $T$ is categorical iff it has no infinite models and exactly one finite model up to isomorphism (and effectivity is completely irrelevant here). This rules out basically all the interesting first-order theories, so that "no first-order theory is categorical" is (in most contexts) *morally* true even if it's technically false.

Comment: OK, then, even though PA+omega rule, and ZF-Inf.+HF rule can have non-standard models, this doesn't affect those theories being the gold standard about what we think it to be true of natural numbers and true of hereditarily finite sets. So my definition of HF-sanity in the other posting being made in relation to them is acceptable if we are to consider that a criterion that we want a foundational theory of mathematics to possess [this is despite my argument of adding it as axiom or not]. I think it would be an ongoing working assumption at the background with any foundational theory anyway?

Comment: @Zuhair Well, this starts to get us into the back-and-forth in your previous question, so I don't want to go there too far - but basically, yes. (But the existence of nonstandard models may affect the common assessment of *first-order logic* as the gold standard for *mathematical reasoning*! I'd argue that it ultimately doesn't, but there have been/are very smart(er) people who disagree with me on this point, including IIRC Vaanaanen and earlier Skolem and Zermelo.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Noah.